# server side Mongodb GridFS file copying

Tags: mongodb, serverside-javascript, gridfs

Per business requirements I need provide possibility to copy content of some file on GridFS. Of course it can be done over domain-specific layer. But in this case I can see some overhead:

- take stream from mongo-server
- allocate memory on business-layer
- read
- place back to mongo-server

Obvious solution is write mongo-side JavaScript that will perform copying in bound of single server.
So my questions:

- Where is the description of API to manage GridFS on JavaScript?
- Is there any issues if my GridFS is sharded?
- Is there any issues if my GridFS is replicated?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You never need to copy a GridFS file within a single server, because GridFS files are immutable: you can create, read, or delete them, but not modify them. So there's no reason to make a copy.

Copying from one server to another should be done via a driver; there's no built-in support for copying directly from a MongoDB server to another.

Comment: Unfortunately I need make copy. Per business rule each file is associated as 1:1 with some entry in another collection. Removing records from collection must cause removing the file. From this requirement growth my question about copying.

Answer (score 0):

The 'normal' js driver does not support GridFS.

You could do it in Node.js. The documentation is here:

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/gridfs.html

For replica-sets the documentation can be found here for Node.js:

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/replicaset.html

For simple one-time copying of some files you can use mongofiles on command line (using a temporary file :( ) :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Tools

```
mongofiles --host HOST get currentfilename
mongofiles --host HOST put -l currentfilename newfilename
rm currentfilename
```

I however don't know how well mongofiles works with sharding and replicas but I would expect it to work.

Comment: you don't get the problem - I don't need JS driver. Driver works on consumer side (saying Java or C++). But there is layer on mongo-side were programmer can place scripts to manage database. Good example mapReduce routines - they are executed at mongo side. So i'm looking for API that can help me avoid overhead with driver (see my pre-requirements). That is why Node.JS is not an answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridfs_session = gridfs.GridFS(mongo.session)
out_file = gridfs_session.get(file_id)
new_copy = gridfs_session.put(out_file, content_type=out_file.content_type)
```